# Подключение к локальному сайту через curl_init и curl_setopt

Tags: php, openserver, передача-данных

Подскажите как подключится к локальному сайту.
Использую OpenServer. Имею вот такой код:

```
$st = http_build_query($post, '', '&');  
$res = $this->api_curl_send('MyLocalSait' . '/save', $st);    

public function api_curl_send($url, $data)
    {
        $user_agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_error($ch)) {
            $error_num = curl_errno($ch);
            return false;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

На продакшене работает, а как настроить чтобы передача работала и на локалке?

Comment: дампните ошибку var_dump(curl_error($ch)) после curl_exec

Comment: Там лишь показывает за SSL сертификат...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прописываете свой сайт в хостах с своим айпишником, таким образом курл будет отрабатывать с вашим локальным доменом.